# Problem in implementing the methods according to test file

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, generics

I was able to make the Constructor and capacity methods to works but don;t know why size(),isFull() and isEmpty() fails.I believe its pretty simple but i am just unable to see a minor error and fix it.Hope someone can clarify what i am doing wrong with thorough explaination.Also,my constructor works with the test file and it passes,but just want to know Is my constructor correct as specified by question?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class SortedArray<T extends Comparable> implements 
java.lang.Iterable<T> {


public SortedArray(int capacity) {

    this.array = (T[]) new Comparable[0];
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.size = 0;
}


public SortedArray(int capacity, T[] data) {


     if(capacity > data.length)
    {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    }
    else {
            this.capacity = data.length;
            }
    this.size = data.length;

    this.array = (T[]) new Comparable[0];
    }


final public int size() {
            return this.size
}


final public int capacity() {
   return this.capacity;
}


final boolean isEmpty() {       
    return size == 0;
}


final boolean isFull(){                        
    return size == capacity;
}

@Override
final public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    // Do not modify this method.
    return Arrays.stream(array).iterator();
}

// Do not modify these data members.
final private T[] array;     // Storage for the array's element
private int size;      // Current size of the array
final private int capacity;  // Maximum size of the array
}
```

//// Test File:

```
 @Test
 public void testConstructor() {
    System.out.println("Constructors");

    SortedArray array = new SortedArray(20);
    assertEquals(array.size(), 0);
    assertEquals(array.capacity(), 20);

    Integer[] data = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    array = new SortedArray(20, data);
    assertEquals(array.size(), 4);
    assertEquals(array.capacity(), 20);

    array = new SortedArray(2, data);
    assertEquals(array.size(), 4);
    assertEquals(array.capacity(), 4);
}

@Test
public void testSize() {
    System.out.println("size");
    SortedArray arr = new SortedArray(10);

    // Array is initially empty
    assertEquals(arr.size(), 0);

    // Inserting elements increases size
    arr.add(12);
    arr.add(13);
    arr.add(14);
    assertEquals(arr.size(), 3);

    // Inserting duplicates increases size
    arr.add(12);
    arr.add(13);
    assertEquals(arr.size(),5);

    // Fill up the array
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        arr.add(i);
    assertEquals(arr.size(), 10);

    // Size does not change when array is full
    arr.add(10);
    arr.add(11);
    assertEquals(arr.size(), 10);

    // Removing elements decreases size
    arr.remove(0);
    arr.remove(1);
    arr.remove(2);
    assertEquals(arr.size(), 7);

    // but removing elements that don't exist doesn't change anything
    arr.remove(100);
    assertEquals(arr.size(), 7);

    // Removing from the empty array doesn't change size.
    SortedArray empty = new SortedArray(10);
    empty.remove(10);
    assertEquals(empty.size(), 0);
}

@Test
public void testCapacity() {
    System.out.println("capacity");
    SortedArray array = new SortedArray(20);
    assertEquals(array.capacity(), 20);

    array = new SortedArray(100);
    assertEquals(array.capacity(), 100);

    Integer[] data = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    array = new SortedArray(20, data);
    assertEquals(array.capacity(), 20);

    array= new SortedArray(5, data);
    assertEquals(array.capacity(), 10);
}

@Test
public void testIsEmpty() {
    System.out.println("isEmpty");
    SortedArray array = new SortedArray(10);
    assertTrue(array.isEmpty());

    array.add(10);
    assertFalse(array.isEmpty());

    array.remove(10);
    assertTrue(array.isEmpty());
}

@Test
public void testIsFull() {
    System.out.println("isFull");
    SortedArray array = new SortedArray(5);

    assertFalse(array.isFull());

    array.add(10);
    array.add(11);
    array.add(12);
    array.add(13);
    array.add(14);
    assertTrue(array.isFull());

    array.remove(10);
    assertFalse(array.isFull());
}

@Test
public void testIterator() {

}


testSize Failed : Expected <0> but was <3>
testCapacity Failed : Expected <5> but was <10>
testConstructor Failed : Expected <0> but was <4>
testisFull Failed : jUnit.framework.AssertionFailedError
testisEmpty Failed : jUnit.framework.AssertionFailedError
```

Comment: I notice in that second constructor, you have this line `this.size = size;`, but `size` is never defined as a local variable. You're just assigning `this.size` back to itself. That seems suspicious.

Comment: Also, in the second constructor, you have written temp = data[T]. How can this program even compile if you use a Comparable to index array and assign it to int variable?

Comment: @ resueman So should i just initialize size to 0 and the constructor will update it when test runs?

Comment: @ chandr3sh That's the problem.I am trying to implement selection sort  in the constructor but was stuck with the logic of generics .I am unable to work with (int capacity, T[] data) parameters of the constructor

Comment: Not dealing with the other issues mentioned, you're (a) comparing data[i] (value) < j (index) which makes no sense.  Since you know T is a comparable you should use `data[i].compareTo(data[j]) < 0` to determine if it's smaller.  (b) You should not be using capacity to store i as you just lost your capacity of 20 (another test will fail) maybe use size? (c) you aren't setting your newly 'sorted' data to the array field - which means you probably don't even need a size field since you can use array.length eventually.

Comment: Update : I am able to make the Constructor and Capacity test to work.But my size ,isFull and isEmpty fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include your "add(T toAdd)" and "remove(T toRemove)" methods, which when I was going through to make the tests pass, was the source of a vast majority of the fails. (Note: a trace of the fails would help, since your adds and removes need to be pretty complicated to fit the design it seems you intend)

Anyways, on to fixing what I *can* see.

In your second constructor, you never actually assign the data you take in. You call `this.array = (T[]) new Comparable[0];` which creates an empty array of type `Comparable`. In reality, you **need** to call `this.array = data` in order to keep what's been given to you.

Another thing, in your `size()` method you forgot to place a semicolon after `this.size`. That tends to prevent things from passing.

Finally, `final private T[] array` can't have `final`, or you'll never be able to add or remove elements.

As a bonus, here are the `add()` and `remove()` methods I used to fit the requirements and make the tests pass (with comments!!!!):

```
    public void add(T t) {
        if (!(size >= capacity)) { //If there's room...
            if (size == 0) //If the array is empty...
                array[0] = t; //Add to first index
            else
                array[size] = t; //Add to next available index
            size++;
        }
    }

    public void remove(T element) {
        if (size <= 0) //If the array is empty...
            return; //Stop here
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i <= this.size(); i++) { //Linear search front-to-back
                if (array[i].equals(element)) { //Find first match
                    array[i] = null; //Delete it
                    size--;
                    if (i != size) { //If the match was not at the end of the array...
                        for (int j = i; j <= (this.size() - 1); j++) 
                            array[j] = array[j + 1]; //Move everything after the match to the left
                    }
                    return; //Stop here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

On a side note, your calls to create `SortedArray` objects should really be parameterized (Using the <> such as `SortedArray<Integer> arr = new SortedArray<Integer>(5, data);`).

Comment: Oh no.I have the iterator method and final data members declared at last,which i have added above.Actually I forgot to post here.But,mine doesn't work in spite of having the data members .Just want to know,did your all methods worked? means did all test passed?

Comment: It's complex to go long way to make the test works but you made it pretty simple.Thanks

Comment: @MeetYeole if the answer solves your problem it’s customary to mark it as correct so others know it worked for you.